# PHP - Cannot read uploaded temporary file

Tags: nginx, php

I'm holding a mail service on my VPS who has a web interface by Roundcube

But I recently found that my Roundcube cannot upload avatars of contacts correctly (which was my first try of uploading avatars). So I had a look of the code and found that it failed when reading properties of the uploaded temporary picture file.

To figure out whether it was caused by Roundcube or not, I wrote a simple script.

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="/upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="test">
        <button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>

<?php
var_dump($_FILES);
var_dump(file_exists($_FILES['test']['tmp_name']));

// read the properties by GD, as what Roundcube does
$props = getimagesize($_FILES['test']['tmp_name']);

var_dump($props);
```

And the output was:

```
array(1) {
    ["test"]=> array(5) {
        ["name"]=> string(23) "kanakurayui_2_small.png"
        ["type"]=> string(9) "image/png"
        ["tmp_name"]=> string(14) "/tmp/php7OxqPq"
        ["error"]=> int(0)
        ["size"]=> int(49294) 
    }
}
bool(false)
bool(false)
```

It looks like that the file was immediately deleted after uploaded, however I could call `move_uploaded_file()` to move the temporary file to another directory (so the mail attachment is functioning properly).

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 with Nginx 1.6.2 and PHP-FPM 5.6.7 from repositories of LaunchPad. And the script works correctly on my local machine whose environment is exactly the same.

I think the problem is caused by some certain configuration of Nginx or PHP, but after checking the configuration files, I could only find configurations about the size and time limit.

I'm really confused now. Please help, thanks.

***UPDATE***

Apache 2.4 + PHP works properly on the same VPS.

Comment: Can you try to install apache and then test to see if this is an nginx or php-fpm problem?

Comment: @insanebits apache 2.4 + php works correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved the problem myself. Thanks @insanebits for reminding.

I had a look at the Nginx log and found the following message:

```
PHP message: PHP Warning:  getimagesize(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/tmp/php1PACw4) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/www) in /var/www/test/upload.php on line 5
```

So I moved the temporary directory to /tmp/php and add /tmp/php to the `open_basedir` setting in php.ini

The reason why it worked on my local machine was that my local PHP configuration was a copy for development and the `open_basedir` was commented out.